# How to read CSV data from a file and write to a List<Object> in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csv, import-from-csv

I'm having a hard time in this problem. I want to import and read a CSV file then transfer the data into a model with a `List<Object>` which is `List<Sender> sender`. Do you have any suggestions?

Here is the FundTransfer Model

```
public class FundTransfer
    {
        public String senderRefId { get; set; }
        public List<Sender> sender { get; set; }
    }
```

The Sender Model

```
public class Sender
    {
        public String name { get; set; }

        public String address { get; set; }

    }
```

The CSV file looks like this

```
senderRefId,name,address
1234,Yoyo,UnitedStates
```

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @VDWWD I've managed to solve my problem using CSVHelper by this code:

```
 using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Filedirectory\\File.xlsx"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FundTransferMap>();
                csv.GetRecords<FundTransfer>().ToList().Dump();
            }
```

I've added a model

```
public class FundTransferMap : ClassMap<FundTransfer>
    {
        public FundTransferMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.senderRefId);
            Map(m => m.sender).ConvertUsing(row =>
            {
                var senderlist = new List<Sender>
            {
                new Sender { name = row.GetField("senderName"),
                    address = row.GetField("senderAddress")
                }
            };
                return senderlist;
            });
        }
    }
```